# How to set default site for IP access on apache vhost environment?

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, virtualhost

I have a vhost environment on Debian Linux with Apache running. It runs fine but I couldn't figure out how to set up a default site for requests that go directly to the servers IP instead of a domain name.

How can I configure Apache to server a specific site for all requests going to the IP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default vhost is the first site in the sites-enabled folder alphabetically. It's traditional to call it something along the lines of 000-default.